# What is the meaning of "私はと比較して何もしないよ彼"?

Tags: translation, meaning, english-to-japanese

Does "私はと比較して何もしないよ彼" mean "I am nothing compared to him"?

I've downloaded this [manga wallpaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKSDt.png)  with the sentence "私はと比較して何もしないよ彼" written on it and "I am nothing compared to her (I changed it to him)" as an English translation as I assumed.

Well, "比較" should be translated as "comparison", "して" is the Te-Form of "する" which is "to do" if I am right. And "彼" is "he".
The rest makes 0 sense to me as I haven't learned that much Japanese grammar and vocabulary yet.

Comment: no it is not. Also Japanese Stack Exchange isn't a translation service. :( If you can show your translation efforts, and that you've been trying to put it together, or identify specific parts that confuse you, the people here are willing to help. But straight "Is this right" / "how do you say this" questions are not allowed.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the warning (?).

Comment: `私はと比較して何もしないと彼` makes no sense. Where did you see it?

Comment: I've downloaded a manga wallpaper with this quote + "I am nothing compared to her (changed it to him)". Well, I've started to learn Japanese a while ago and this sentence made no sense to me neither. So I wanted to ask whether it's right.

Comment: 「私はと比較して何もしない**よ**彼女」て書いてありますね。。（しないよ, not しないと.）

Comment: i've never seen the construction と比較して before.... my education is lacking.

Comment: ... wouldn't it be more grammatical to say 私は彼女と比較して何もしないよ。　❓

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a mangled linear (machine?) translation

- I am → 私は
- nothing → 何もしないよ
- compared to → と比較して
- her → 彼女

Putting the Japanese translation first, you might believe that the English sentence is a translation of the Japanese sentence, but I think it is probably the other way around.

Needless to say, it's not a natural way to translate the sentence

> I am nothing compared to her